# Notation arb(x)

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, set-theory, notation

Suppose we have extended $ZF$ by adding to $ZF$ an unary function symbol $arb$ (an arbitrary element of a set) and a corresponding axiom "For every non-empty set $S$, $arb(S)$ is in $S$".
Will be the resulting theory a conservative extension of $ZF$?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is an obvious yes, given a proof there are only finitely many instances of $arb$ in the formulas and you can just replace each instance with the "mini-proof" that $S\neq\varnothing$ therefore we can fix some $s\in S$. This happens finitely many times so we're good without appealing to the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Asaf Surely not. Using replacement, I can (uniformly!) construct a choice function for every family of non-empty sets, so in particular this theory proves the axiom of choice!

Comment: @Zhen Lin, oh yeah. It seems like you can easily get global choice from this simply take $\lbrace(x,arb(x))\mid x\neq\varnothing\rbrace$. I was thinking in terms of a "dynamic oracle" so to speak... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how the remaining axioms of ZF are altered (or not). For example, do we broaden the scheme of replacement to apply to formulas of set theory which contain the symbol "$arb$"? If so, then as Zhen Lin says the resulting theory proves the axiom of choice: given a collection of sets $\mathcal{A}=\lbrace A_i: i\in I\rbrace$, applying replacement to the formula "$x=arb(S)$" as $S$ ranges over the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ yields a choice function. If we don't do this - that is, if we have replacement and separation only for sentences of the language of set theory without "$arb$" - then we do in fact get a conservative extension: given any model $\mathcal{M}$ of ZF, let $arb$ pick any element from each element of $\mathcal{M}$ (I guess I'm using Choice in the ambient universe to do this, but if all we care about is not proving any new theorems, then this can be gotten rid of by Shoenfield absoluteness); the resulting extension is a model of ZF with $arb$.

Comment: Well pointed on the delicate reasoning about the replacement schema. Why doesn't the "algorithm" I suggested in my first comment work on a syntactical level, which would then rid of the need for choice in the meta-theory?

Comment: There are only finitely many *explicit* instances of $arb$ in any proof; but there may be one "mass-instance" of $arb$ being applied to every member of a set of sets, via Replacement. The second step of your algorithm involves replacing each actual instance of $arb$ by a specific choice, which does work if there are only finitely many $arb$s, but fails if we have a mass instance of $arb$. (Wow, that didn't come out nearly as clearly as it sounded in my head. :p )

Comment: Well, sure if we modify the replacement schema. But what if we keep replacement as in the original ZF?

Comment: Hm, I think what Noah is saying is that even inside one sentence, we may end up evaluating $\textrm{arb}(x)$ for infinitely many $x$. (For example, $\forall x . (\exists y \in x) \to \textrm{arb}(x) \in x$.)

Comment: Zhen Lin, yes. But this is hardly enough to give a choice function. 

Comment: To avoid choice in the ambient universe, you could also use the following argument: If $\varphi$ is a consequence of ZF+arb but not ZF, then there is a countable Henkin model of ZF+$\lnot \varphi$. This model can be expanded to a model of ZF+arb without choice. (But Shoenfield is fine, too.) 

Comment: @Goldstern: Yeah, Shoenfield is overkill. @Asaf: I'm not sure I understand - evaluating $arb$ at infinitely many inputs is precisely finding a choice function for that collection of inputs. This affects a strong version of conservativity in the following way: we want to prove that every model $M$ of $ZF$ can be extended to a model $M'$ of $ZF+arb$. Well, living within $V$ a model of $ZF+\neg AC$ with $X$ a non-well-orderable set, if $M\in V$ is a transitive model of $ZF$ containing $X$, then (according to $V$) $M$ cannot be expanded to a model of $ZF+arb$.

Comment: Of course it does nothing to affect the usual notion of conservativity - "no new theorems." But it is interesting to me that that is a distinction, in the absence of choice.

Comment: I think I jus don't see how we can prove anything without augmented replacement here. The fact that there are elements in non-empty sets is fine; but any appeal to infinitely many $arb$'s is going through replacement, which we didn't augment to allow $arb$. 

Comment: @Asaf: what I'm saying is that there's two forms of conservativity - no new theorems, and "every model of the old theory extends to one of the new theory" - and (when we restrict replacement to its original formulation) the former is outright provable, but the latter requires choice in the ambient universe. If you're asking about whether ZF+$arb$ is conservative (in the weaker sense) over ZF when replacement is taken as its old version, it definitely is: the assumption of $AC$ in the ambient universe lets us prove "strong conservativity," and hence "no new theorems," (cont'd)

Comment: and the latter statement is purely arithmetic, hence absolute, so already a consequence of $ZF$. So basically, my claim is this: if we interpret replacement as just ranging over formulas not including "$arb$," then $ZF+arb$ is conservative in the weaker sense over $ZF$, and the statement "$ZF+arb$ is conservative over $ZF$ in the stronger sense" requires some choice. (In particular, that statement together with "every set is contained in a transitive set model of $ZF$" implies $AC$.)

Comment: This is the second time in just two days I am involved in a discussion where apparently all the parties generally agree, but don't know it. 

Comment: Shoenfield absoluteness (or ZF, for that matter) is definitely an overkill. When the replacement schema is not expanded, $\mathit{arb}$ is nothing else than a plain old Skolem function, and the conservativity of Skolem extensions of any theory is provable in weak fragments of arithmetic (for sequential theories, it can be proved in $S^1_2$, using a nice forcing argument by Avigad).

Comment: Also, no one seems to have mentioned that if we *do* expand the replacement schema to the new language, the theory not only proves AC, but is in fact a conservative extension of ZFC.

Comment: @Emil: isn't the argument that $ZF^++arb$ (replacement expanded version) is conservative over $ZFC$ just a sub-argument of the proof that $NBG$ is conservative over $ZFC$ (i.e., an appropriate class forcing adding no new sets)?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just thought it should be explicitly mentioned somewhere on this page.